# Simple MatLab Issue Regarding fplot and function files

Tags: matlab

The explicit problem is as follows: Write a function and use the fplot command to plot f(x)=x^3-x+8 versus x, for values of x from 0 to 100.

The easy way, throw the following code into matlab and call it a day:

```
Testing = @(x) x^3 - x + 8
fplot(Testing, [0 100])
```

and done!

but I want to take a slightly more 'difficult' approach. Basically I made a seperate .m file that has the following:

```
function [y] = blah(x)
y = (x^3) - x + 8;
end
```

and a script with the following

```
fplot('blah', [0 100])
```

but it doesn't work. whyyyy ( i keep getting a positive-sloped line)

Thanks!

Comment: I tried it on my pc and both are giving the same results!, so what is the problem ?

Comment: You need an `@` with your call to that function. See the duplicate target and gnovice's comment on the accepted answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB odd 'Too many input arguments' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47636391/matlab-odd-too-many-input-arguments-error)

Answer (score 0):

In my version of Matlab (2016b), it works when `blah` is not a string:

```
blah = @(x) (x.^3) - x + 8;

plot(0:100, blah(0:100),'r.-')
hold all
fplot(blah,[0 100],'kx-')
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. The OP is asking why it does not work with `function [y] = blah(x)`

Comment: @SardarUsama, issue is the same whether blah is in an independent file or an inline function. `fplot` plots x = 1:100 and y = 1:100 in both cases. Using the function handle solves the issue.

Comment: The OP already knows that it works with `blah = @(x) (x.^3) - x + 8;` and clearly is not asking what you have answered